# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport"

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoapods, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I've installed Firebase In App Messaging according to the guide: https://rnfirebase.io/in-app-messaging/usage

When I run `pod install`, I get this:

```
Using firebase.json from '/../app/firebase.json'
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBCrashlytics: [RNFB] Crashlytics Configuration
Detected React Native module pods for RNFBAnalytics, RNFBApp, RNFBCrashlytics, RNFBDynamicLinks, and RNFBInAppMessaging
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (= 2.0.2, ~> 2.0)

  In Podfile:
    RNFBInAppMessaging (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging`) was resolved to 6.4.0, which depends on
      Firebase/InAppMessaging (~> 6.13.0) was resolved to 6.13.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.13.0) was resolved to 6.13.0, which depends on
          FirebaseCore (= 6.4.0) was resolved to 6.4.0, which depends on
            FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.2.3, which depends on
              GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 2.0)

    RNFBInAppMessaging (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging`) was resolved to 6.4.0, which depends on
      Firebase/InAppMessaging (~> 6.13.0) was resolved to 6.13.0, which depends on
        FirebaseInAppMessaging (~> 0.15.5) was resolved to 0.15.6, which depends on
          GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 1.0)


You have either:
 * changed the constraints of dependency `GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport` inside your development pod `RNFBInAppMessaging`.
   You should run `pod update GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport` to apply changes you've made.
```

I've tried a few things including `pod install --repo-update` but nothing helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `pod 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics', '1.2.1'` to the Podfile might be a workaround since that [podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/8/3/c/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/1.2.1/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.podspec.json) only needs GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport 1.x.

Those Firebase versions are several months old - so another approach would be to encourage React Native to update the wrappers.