# Error Installing Firebase In App Messaging in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am trying to install the Firebase In-App Messaging component in my app
I had installed my existing firebase components before, below is what my package.json looks like for firebase stuff before installing in-app messaging.

```
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.7.1",
```

So I decided to

`npm install --save @react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging@^6.7.1`

when i try to `pod install` i get the following error:

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (= 3.0.0, ~> 3.0)

  In Podfile:
    RNFBInAppMessaging (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging`) was resolved to 6.7.1, which depends on
      Firebase/InAppMessaging (~> 6.13.0) was resolved to 6.13.0, which depends on
        FirebaseInAppMessaging (~> 0.15.5) was resolved to 0.15.6, which depends on
          GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 1.0)

    RNFBMessaging (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging`) was resolved to 6.7.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Messaging (~> 6.13.0) was resolved to 6.13.0, which depends on
        FirebaseMessaging (~> 4.1.9) was resolved to 4.1.10, which depends on
          FirebaseCore (~> 6.2) was resolved to 6.4.0, which depends on
            FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.2.4, which depends on
              GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 3.0)
```

am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod “GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61252212/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-googledatatransportcctsupp)

It is happening because you are apparently using firebase 5.x.x which is deprecated. In a nut shell you need to go for the work around recommended in the issue mentioned above.

Or you can upgrade to firebase 6.x.x

Comment: Hey, I am using Firebase 6, I migrated a month back

Comment: Okay @Epiczzor I just noticed that and I dont see any other reason to get this error. Try to remove Podfile.lock using

`rm -rf Podfile.lock`

and then do a `pod install` once again

Answer (score 2):

1. Update cocopod (https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html)
2. Delete pod lock file
3. `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a conflict in your podfile. Deleting your podfile and running `pod install --repo-update` might help here. Also be sure that you don't have any firebase pods leftover from an older version (see [here](https://rnfirebase.io/migrating-to-v6#remove-the-rnfirebase-pod)).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue - nothing I could find was working.

Eventually I **upped my Platform version in the podfile to 14.0** deleted node modules / yarn.lock and podfile.lock.  Re ran yarn install && pod install - worked.

[image]